# Show/Hide Form Fields in Squarespace

Tags: java, jquery, forms, hide, show

I am trying to show/hide form fields in a Squarespace form based upon the value selected in a dropdown menu. The dropdown menu has a list of values from 1-10. The intent is to display 2 form fields for each number selected from the dropdown menu. For value 1, I want the form fields titled "Serial Number" and "Confirm Serial Number" to ALWAYS be displayed. For value 2, I want to show "Serial Number 2" and "Confirm Serial Number 2". And so on for values 3-10.

Here is a screenshot of the form as it is now with everything displayed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHhWt.png)

Comment: Did you mean java or js ?

Comment: Can you share your html code plz

Comment: Can you share some exemple of you data ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for in terms of data. I will share the html below.
file:///Users/jerroddouglas/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202021-03-02%20at%2011.22.13%20AM.png

Comment: https://ibb.co/F43MHCs

Comment: I just understand after reading multiple time, sorry i'm a french baguette, yeah it's quiet simple i will send you. just let me few sec. You just need to create a function which is call when you change the value of your select and create dynamicly the input

Answer (score 0):

You can get the serial element with `` document.getElementById(`serial-input-${index}`) ``

You can get the serial confirm element with `` document.getElementById(`serial-input-confirm-${index}`) ``

```
<p>Number of products</p>
<select id="select" onChange="create.input()"></select>
<div id="input"></div>
```

```
const create = {
  select: () => {
        let select = document.getElementById('select')
    // Create 1-10 number of products
    new Array(10).fill(0).forEach((x, i) => {
      let option = document.createElement('option')
      option.innerHTML = (i+1)
      option.value = (i+1)
      select.appendChild(option)
    })
  },
  input: () => {
    let input  = document.getElementById('input')
    let select = document.getElementById('select')
    console.log(select.value)
    // Remove all child
    input.innerHTML = ''
    // Create the same number of input has you select in select ...
    const size = parseInt(select.value, 10)
        new Array(size).fill(0).forEach((x, i) => {
      console.log(i)
      let p_input = create.p_input(i)
      p_input.forEach(x => input.appendChild(x))
    })    
  },
  p_input: index => {
    let name = `erial number` + (index > 0 ? ' ' + (index+1) : '')
    
    let serial_p = document.createElement('p')
    serial_p.innerHTML = 'S' + name
    serial_p.id = 'p-serial-' + index
    serial_p.class = 'p-serial'
    
    let serial_p_confirm = document.createElement('p')
    serial_p_confirm.innerHTML = 'Confirm s' + name
    serial_p_confirm.id = 'pc-serial-' + index
    serial_p_confirm.class =  'pc-serial'

        let serial_input         = document.createElement('input')
    serial_input.type = "text"
    serial_input.id   = "serial-input-" + index
    serial_input.class =  'serial-input'

    let serial_input_confirm = document.createElement('input')
    serial_input_confirm.type = "text"
    serial_input_confirm.id   = "serial-input-confirm-" + index
    serial_input_confirm.class =  'serial-input'
    
    return [serial_p, serial_input, serial_p_confirm, serial_input_confirm]
  }
}
create.select()
create.input()
```

for exemple here its what i get when i click on 5.[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What does this mean? You can get the serial element with document.getElementById(`serial-input-${index}`)

You can get the serial confirm element with document.getElementById(`serial-input-confirm-${index}`)

Comment: i'm sure you will ask after how can i get the value so i say before you ask : you can have the element with ```document.getElementById(serial-input-${index})``` for exemple to have the value of serial number 5 you do ```document.getElementById(serial-input-4).value``` for the confirm serial number 5 you do ```document.getElementById(serial-input-confirm-4).value``` so (5-1) = 4

Comment: Plz, if it's what you want valide my answer. That give me reputation point. I NEED IT ! (spongbob meme)

Comment: I don't think that will work... Here is a link to the actual div ids. https://ibb.co/CwxXMR7
I'm not sure how to apply the code you offered inside of the html.